# Passing parameter to MyBatis @Select

Tags: java, parameter-passing, mybatis

I am writing my fist MyBatis application and I stuck around @Select. I do not know what is the problem with my @Select definition, everything seems fine but I got a `Parameter not found` exception.

I have followed the same pattern when I pass parameters to my my @Insert statement and it works without problem.

I use MyBatis 3.4.2.

**This is my @Select:**

```
@Select("SELECT * "
        + "FROM configuration "
        + "WHERE key_name = #{key} AND "
        +       "(#{userId} IS NULL AND user_id IS NULL) OR user_id = #{userId} AND "
        +       "status = 1")
Configuration findByKeyAndUserId(String key, Long userId);
```

**The exception what I got:**

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'key' not found. Available parameters are [arg1, arg0, param1, param2]
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'key' not found. Available parameters are [arg1, arg0, param1, param2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a single parameter object, properties are accessed directly through getter or key  set for a map. When you want to pass multiple parameters in the method, you have to name the parameters with annotation:

```
Configuration findByKeyAndUserId(@Param("key") String key, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

This annotation based syntax actually behave like a key-value map. Keys are provided by @Param. The name you choose for parameter variables are not visible.

Answer (score 2):

Please try `-parameters` compile option provided since JDK 8. You can omit a `@Param` annotation.

See https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/549

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to configure maven and intellij to use "-parameters"? I added <arg>-parameters</arg> to my maven-compiler-plugin but there is no impact. Intellij: Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional command line parameters but it does not work. Maybe I need to spend more time on it :(

Comment: Maven:
See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs.

Comment: IntelliJ:
You are right !! However you should be rebuild your project. (execute "Build > Rebuild Project").

Comment: Maven:

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <compilerArgs>
   <arg>-parameters</arg>
  </compilerArgs>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

It's work fine.

Comment: Eclipse:
Java > Compiler > "Store information about method parameters( usable via reflection) is checked